# EADDRINUSE address already in use

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

When I run `dnu . kestrel` to start up the asp.net 5 server on OS X, and then press `CTL+C` to stop the server, then run `dnu . kestrel` a second time, I receive the following exception:

> Sullys-MacBook-Pro:Test1App Sully$ dnx . kestrel
>
> System.Exception: Error -48 EADDRINUSE address already in use
>     at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.Check (Int32 statusCode) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.listen (Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvStreamHandle handle, Int32 backlog, Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.uv_connection_cb cb) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvStreamHandle.Listen (Int32 backlog, System.Action`4 callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] in :0 
>   ^C

The terminal acts like the server is running, because I have to press `CTL+C` again to terminate the server process. While it is "running", I can't actually navigate to it from a browser.

Is there a proper way to shut down the server as I change code, without having to kill the terminal, open a new one, navigate to my project directory and re-start kestrel?

I have seen other errors related to this on SO; they all seemed related to Android. I haven't seen anything related to kestrel and the `dnu` for `EADDRINUSE`

Answer (score 2):

On OS X pressing the Enter key in the terminal should stop kestrel. What is happening is that Cntrl-C puts it into a suspended state and you would then have to find the process and issues a unix kill command for that process. The issue https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/26 refers. Though I am sure I say a thread saying it was going to fixed so that either Cntrl-C or Cntrl-Z would would work on all environments for Kestrel

Comment: I had seen that thread about them making it work in all platforms, and in there they mentioned entered kills it. For me it doesn't seem to. When I press enter, a new blank line is made in terminal; the server keeps running

Comment: Try pressing enter a few times. That was noted as sometimes being required.

Comment: I got it to work but only by assigning a new port like so:

"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:17202",

did you guys ever manage to find another solution?

Comment: No, when they announced that dnx/dnu was being replaced by the new `dotnet` CLI, I stopped working in RC1.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a OSX question, but I was getting this exception in Windows after I changed `--server.urls=http://*:9000` to `--server.urls=http://*:9000;https://*:9000` to attempt to support https. It look like [the semi-colon is not supported](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/211).

The same is true in RC2 with .UseUrls("http://*:9000", "https://*:9000")